# `PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so'

Tags: php, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried running this `php -v` in wsl ubuntu 16.04 but got this php warning

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so'
>   (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

I've search using google but I did not find direct answer that address the problem.

What to do with this

I have php installed in the system

> PHP 7.2.3-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2018
>   11:18:25) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.3-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: It seems like in your php.ini you are loading the mcrypt extension but you have not installed it or it is at a differen location!

Answer (score 0):

[PHP 7.2 does not support mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php)
You can still [install it](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-mcrypt-extension.html) as unofficial PECL extension

Comment: cant install on this part `sudo pecl7.2-sp install --nodeps mcrypt-snapshot` don't know why